# PTIJ: Erev Rav's Eruv Rav

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Did the Erev Rav have their own Eruv Rav that they used for carrying on Shabbos?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Yes, and the Eruv Rav was instituted by the Erev Rav's Rav on Erev Shabbat.

Comment: @Harel13 the question is did the Erev Rav have an Eruv Rav who would carry on their behalf.